# BGE how can I run a sound file while a key is pressed?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, audio

In the BGE, how can I run a sound file while a key is pressed, but have it stop as soon as it's released?

Comment: So are those two questions ? Your title should match the content dude...
Take the plane and delete its face keeping the edges, then hit ALT + C and select "curve from mesh". For the sound, make an empty or whatever object, in the logic bricks panel, add a KEYBOARD sensor with "true level triggering" on, and connect it with and "AND" controller to a SOUND actuator...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a sound play on a key press and stop on the release of that key by using the "Play Stop" setting on the *sound actuator*

[image]

When the sound actuator is set to "Play Stop," when it receives a positive pulse from the connected controller, it will start playing the selected audio file. When it receives a negative pulse form the connected controller, it will stop playing the selected audio file. In this case, we are using a Keyboard sensor, which simply sends a positive pulse to the connected controller on key press, and a negative pulse on release.